# Python program to run commands in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, command

I need to run a command in anaconda prompt but I want to write a python code to do it for me, any idea about how to do it?

Comment: Do want to run your python codes on anaconda prompt?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @БогданОпир I am working with a library that only runs on anaconda prompt. My research involves using this library's commands a lot, so it would be indeed easier to write a python code to run the commands automatically (instead of manually). I can do such a thing on cmd, but not the anaconda prompt. Tried to access it through the OS library but it didn't work.

Comment: @LazyCoder No. I want to write a program to run some specific commands on the anaconda prompt itself. Hope I have explained it well enough!